# How do I add the Table of Contents to the Table of Contents with a section number?

Tags: article, subsection

I'm writing a report in LaTeX (article class) that needs to follow a specific format which includes listing the ToC within the ToC with a section number. For example:

### 1.2  Table of Contents

1 Section Title

1.1 Cover Page

1.2 Table of Contents

1.3 Next Subsection

etc.

I've tried `\tocbibind` as is recommended on the similar questions I've found. That adds a Table of Contents line, but does not adjust the section numbering nor the Table of Contents header. The header is still sized like a `\section` heading and is not numbered when it should be formatted like a subsection. Instead of looking like above, it looks more like

## Table of Contents

1 Section Title

1.1 Cover Page

Table of Contents

1.2 Next Subsection

etc.

I have sort of had success with

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\subsection{Table of Contents}}}
```

in that the ToC header and list look like what I need. However, now all my `\subsection` titles now have regular text, indented duplicates underneath the subsection headers, like so:

### **1.4 Subsection**

1.4 Subsection

1.4.1 Subsubsection

Obviously that looks absurd. Can anyone recommend a better solution? I would ignore this formatting altogether (I think it looks stupid and having the ToC in the ToC at all, let alone numbered, is pointless) if it weren't such an important report.

Answer (score 3):

What a strange layout. I wish that you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you had tried an, specifically, the general layout of your document divisions (`\section`, `\subsection`, etc).

I have made a guess at an MWE that might guide you in the right direction, in particular regarding the numbering of the ToC.

```
% tocprob.tex  SE 615402

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@cftmaketoctitle}{% set title as a \subsection
  \subsection{\contentsname}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
\subsection{Cover page}
\tableofcontents
\subsection{Next subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW I'm confused about whether you are talking about `\section` or `\subsection`. In your title you say "section number" but in your examples you show "subsection numbers".
--- GOM